# Multiple questions type setting querries

Tags: exam

I have used the codes given in previous question by someone else on the same title.

Exactly i want to produce all four options like
(a)
(b)
(c)
(d)

because of the length of the option is large so the following given codes doesn't work properly to the my desirable outcomes.

Please help me.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{exam}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb,dsfont}
    \setlength\parindent{0pt}
        %usage \choice{ }{ }{ }{ }
        %(A)(B)(C)(D)
        \newcommand{\fourch}[4]{
        \par
                \begin{tabular}{*{4}{@{}p{0.23\textwidth}}}
                (a)~#1 & (b)~#2 & (c)~#3 & (d)~#4
                \end{tabular}
        }

        %(A)(B)
        %(C)(D)
        \newcommand{\twoch}[4]{

                \begin{tabular}{*{2}{@{}p{0.46\textwidth}}}
                (a)~#1 & (b)~#2
                \end{tabular}
        \par
                \begin{tabular}{*{2}{@{}p{0.46\textwidth}}}
                (c)~#3 & (d)~#4
                \end{tabular}
        }

        %(A)
        %(B)
        %(C)
        %(D)
        \newcommand{\onech}[4]{
        \par
              (a)~#1 \par (b)~#2 \par (c)~#3 \par (d)~#4
        }

        \newlength\widthcha
        \newlength\widthchb
        \newlength\widthchc
        \newlength\widthchd
        \newlength\widthch
        \newlength\tabmaxwidth

        \setlength\tabmaxwidth{0.96\textwidth}
        \newlength\fourthtabwidth
        \setlength\fourthtabwidth{0.25\textwidth}
        \newlength\halftabwidth
        \setlength\halftabwidth{0.5\textwidth}

      \newcommand{\choice}[4]{%
      \settowidth\widthcha{AM.#1}\setlength{\widthch}{\widthcha}%
      \settowidth\widthchb{BM.#2}%
      \ifdim\widthch<\widthchb\relax\setlength{\widthch}{\widthchb}\fi%
      \settowidth\widthchb{CM.#3}%
      \ifdim\widthch<\widthchb\relax\setlength{\widthch}{\widthchb}\fi%
      \settowidth\widthchb{DM.#4}%
      \ifdim\widthch<\widthchb\relax\setlength{\widthch}{\widthchb}\fi%
      \ifdim\widthch<\fourthtabwidth
        \fourch{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}
      \else\ifdim\widthch<\halftabwidth
        \ifdim\widthch>\fourthtabwidth
          \twoch{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}
        \else
          \onech{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}
        \fi
      \fi\fi
    }
    \begin{document}
     \begin{questions}
    \question If $a = 3 + i$ and $z = 2 - 3i$ then the points on the Argand diagram
    representing az, 3az and - az are
    \choice{Vertices of a right angled triangle}{ Vertices of an equilateral 
    triangle}{Vertices of an isosceles triangle}{Collinear}
    \question If z represents a complex number then $\arg (z) + \arg\left(\bar z\right)$ is 
    \choice{$\dfrac{\pi}{4}$}{$\dfrac{\pi}{2}$}{0}{$\dfrac{\pi}{6}$}
    \question If the amplitude of a complex number is $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ then the number is
    \choice{ purely imaginary}{purely real}{0}{neither real nor imaginary}
    \question The value of $i + i^{22} + i^{23} + i^{24} + i^{25}$ is
    \choice{i}{-i}{1}{-1}
    \question The volume generated by 
    rotating the triangle with vertices at
    (0, 0), (3, 0) and (3, 3) about x-axis is
    \choice{$18\pi$}{$2\pi$}{$36\pi$}{$9\pi$}\end{questions}
    \end{document}

    \end{document}
```

I have used above codes from the previous question on the above said title.

Comment: Welcome, can you add a link to the question you are referring to?

Comment: What is the precise question?

Answer (score 1):

*Updates with Gonzalo Medina comment to adjust formatting*

I would just use the question types provided by the `exam` package directly, without the commands you are defining. Notice the two environments available `choices` and `oneparchoices`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{exam}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb,dsfont}
    \renewcommand\choicelabel{(\alph{choice})}
    \renewcommand\choiceshook{\setlength{\leftmargin}{20pt}}

    \begin{document}
     \begin{questions}
    \question If $a = 3 + i$ and $z = 2 - 3i$ then the points on the Argand diagram
    representing az, 3az and - az are
    \begin{choices}
        \choice Vertices of a right angled triangle
        \choice Vertices of an equilateral triangle
        \choice Vertices of an isosceles triangle
        \choice Collinear
    \end{choices}
    \question If z represents a complex number then $\arg (z) + \arg\left(\bar z\right)$ is 
    \begin{choices}
        \choice $\dfrac{\pi}{4}$
        \choice $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$
        \choice 0
        \choice $\dfrac{\pi}{6}$
    \end{choices}
    \question If the amplitude of a complex number is $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ then the number is
    \begin{choices}
        \choice purely imaginary
        \choice purely real
        \choice 0
        \choice neither real nor imaginary
    \end{choices}
    \question The value of $i + i^{22} + i^{23} + i^{24} + i^{25}$ is

    \begin{oneparchoices}
        \choice i
        \choice -i
        \choice 1
        \choice -1
    \end{oneparchoices}
    \question The volume generated by 
    rotating the triangle with vertices at (0, 0), (3, 0) and (3, 3) about x-axis is

    \begin{oneparchoices}
        \choice $18\pi$
        \choice $2\pi$
        \choice $36\pi$
        \choice $9\pi$
    \end{oneparchoices}        
\end{questions}
    \end{document}

    \end{document}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: You can add these:    `\renewcommand\choicelabel{(\alph{choice})}
    \renewcommand\choiceshook{\setlength{\leftmargin}{20pt}}` to get the desired formatting.